# Rails Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker

I'm building a rails app and I'm having trouble installing docker.

The build works, but when I try to create the DB with this command :

```
docker-compose run web bundle exec rails db:create
```

it throws this error :

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Address not available
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've try to rename the host from localhost to db, it didn't work and I also tried to edit my etc/hosts.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  localhost:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - localhost
    working_dir: /myapp
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.2-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base postgresql-dev tzdata libxml2-dev libxslt-dev nodejs yarn

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
COPY package.json /myapp/package.json

RUN gem install bundler:2.1.2
RUN bundle install

COPY . /myapp

RUN yarn install --check-files
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password:
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
```

/etc/hosts

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
127.0.0.1 postgres
```

How can I fix this issue ? I'm not sure what I'm missing!

Answer (score 2):

In Docker each "service" runs in its own container. So you would have the Rails app and the database in different containers. Each service is conceptually speaking a different server.

Your error (`Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1)..`) suggests that your Rails application is looking for a database engine on the same machine. That DB is running on a separate server.

In a docker-compose file each service is addressable by its name. So change the connection string or setting in your Rails app from `localhost` to `db` or something.

Edit: I just now see that you named your DB server `localhost`, that's asking for trouble. Change that to `db` or something? :)

Comment: Hi Christophe, I've changed the name of my host to : db. 
Now I have the following error : could not translate host name "db" to address: Name does not resolve
```Couldn't create 'myapp_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name does not resolve```

Comment: That is strange, it should work according to the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/. Have you tried dropping into a shell on the webapp and manually pinging `db`? The error suggests your rails app does not know how to resolve `db` to an ip address, which it should.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by : 'dropping into a shell on the webapp and manually pinging db'?

Comment: Start your containers and then `docker-compose exec -it <container> /bin/bash` that will give you a shell to investigate in the running container. Quick question: did you change the name in docker-compose.yml too?

Comment: Yup I changed the name in docker-compose.yml too. If I use this command : ```docker container ls``` I should see my containers no ? The list is empty ..

Comment: No, you should use `docker ps -a` to see your containers.

Comment: So I've started my container with : ```docker start <containter_id>``` and I tried your command and it says ```Execute a command in a running container```.
I'm not sure what I'm missing ..

Comment: Your docker container probably errors out while starting. Check the logs using `docker-compose logs`.

Comment: ```docker-compose logs``` throw this error : 
```Attaching to myapp_db_1
db_1   | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
db_1   |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
db_1   | 
db_1   |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
db_1   |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
db_1   | 
db_1   |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
```

Comment: There we go. Your container immediatly stops because it is not configured properly. Have a look at the documentation here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ You need to provide the root password at aminimum (add `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example` env variable).

Comment: Ok so I've added it like so ```environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example```at the same level as volumes but it still throws the same error

Comment: I've also added POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust" and restarted my containers and it did the trick ..... Thanks so much for your time !!!!